# Не получается очистить таблицу в Postgres в JUnit тестах

Tags: java, postgresql, junit

Есть тест, в котором в самом начале в методе `setUp()` я хочу очистить таблицу вот таким `sql` запросом:

```
String sql =  "Truncate \"" + tableName + "\"";
```

Для этого у меня есть хелпер который формирует эту строку и после этого делаете `execute`, выглядет это так:

```
@Test
public void setUp(){
   DBHelper.getInstance().truncateTable(myTableName);
}

public class DBHelper {
    public void truncateTable(String tableName) {
        log.debug("truncateTable() called with: tableName = [" + tableName + "]");
        String sql =  "Truncate \"" + tableName + "\"";
        try {
            this.executeSyncRawQuery(tableName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Can not truncate table [" + tableName + "] with sql [" + sql  +"]", e);
        }
    }

    public void executeSyncRawQuery(String sql) throws Exception {

        if (sql == null) {
            throw new Exception("executeSyncRawQuery: can not process nullable sql string");
        }
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;

        connection = getSource().getConnection();

        statement = connection.createStatement();

        statement.execute(sql);

        if (!statement.isClosed()) statement.close();
        if (connection != null) connection.close();
    }
}
```

В результате получаю ошибку:

> Can not truncate table [feature] with sql [Truncate "feature"] Caused
>   with: ERROR: syntax error at or near "feature"   Position: 1. Stack
>   trace:
>   [org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455), org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155),
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288),
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430),
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356),
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:303),
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:289),
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:266),
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:262),
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source),
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43),
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498),
>   org.postgresql.ds.PGPooledConnection$StatementHandler.invoke(PGPooledConnection.java:423),
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.execute(Unknown Source),
>   com.common.db.general.DBHelper.executeSyncRawQuery(DBHelper.java:1073),
>   com.common.db.general.DBHelper.truncateTable(DBHelper.java:389),
>   com.common.BaseRequestConsumerTest.lambda$tearDown$0(BaseRequestConsumerTest.java:81),
>   java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75),
>   com.common.BaseRequestConsumerTest.tearDown(BaseRequestConsumerTest.java:71),
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method),
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62),
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43),
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498),
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47),
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12),
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44),
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33),
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271),
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70),
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50),
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238),
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63),
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236),
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53),
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229),
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309),
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160),
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68),
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51),
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242),
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)]

Но если в методе `setUp()` я извлеку sql  без вызова метода `truncateTable()` вот так:

```
@Test
public void setUp(){
    String sql = "Truncate \"" + myTableName + "\"";

    try {
        DBHelper.getInstance().executeSyncRawQuery(sql);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

То так все работает как надо. И не могу понять в чем разница что я это  `sql` формирую в тесте а потом с этим `sql` вызываю хелпер, что я просто вызываю хелпер  и он сам формирует и извлекает этот `sql`. Где я  могу ошибатся?

Comment: `this.executeSyncRawQuery(tableName);` - не та переменная передается

Comment: омг, спасибо, все заработало)